# How do I integrate Tinymce with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, tinymce

This is how I have done the coding.

Please I need someones help for this.

Below is the HTML and Javascript code

```
<html>
[<head>][2]
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"> 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui- 
tinymce/0.0.19/tinymce.js'></script>
<!-- AngularUI TinyMCE -->

</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
<form>
<textarea ui-tinymce="tinymceOptions" class = "text1" id="mytextarea" 
>Hello, World!</textarea>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript file:

```
var myAppModule = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.tinymce']);
myAppModule.controller('myController', function($scope) {
tinyMCE.init({
selector: "text1"
})

$scope.tinymceOptions = {
plugins: 'link image code',
toolbar: 'undo redo | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright | 
code'
};
})
```

This is what I get after I have run the code

Comment: help with what? whats the error?

Comment: Tinymce is still not working.

Comment: Is that the error you get `Tinymce is still not working.`? Be clear whats happening and what you want to happen.

Comment: i am trying to add the image..Please hold on

Comment: angular.min_1.js:123 Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$controller/ctrlreg?p0=editorTiny
    at angular.min_1.js:6
    at angular.min_1.js:93
    at Object.<anonymous> (viewDirective.ts:378)
    at angular.min_1.js:17
    at ra (angular.min_1.js:85)
    at n (angular.min_1.js:70)
    at g (angular.min_1.js:61)
    at angular.min_1.js:61
    at angular.min_1.js:66
    at updateView (viewDirective.ts:301) "<ui-view class="ng-scope">"
(anonymous) @ angular.min_1.js:123

Comment: Above is the error I get in the console

Comment: If you have still not understood then please let me know in some easy steps to integrate tinymce in angularjs without bower

Comment: don't use angular.min.js. Use the unminified development version when developing. Use the minified one in production. Also you can edit your question, no need to add error n stuff in comments.

Comment: See, the project is ready for deployment. I have recently joined this project. I have been told to replace the CKeditor with Tinymce. If I make any change, the complete code will then throw an error

Comment: The error messages of minified version will make no sense. You need to use unminified, read and fix the errors, then use minified again on production.

Answer (score 2):

Please, consider the following code, which should work:

```js
var myAppModule = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.tinymce']);
myAppModule.controller('myController', function ($scope) {
    tinyMCE.init({
        selector: "text1"
    })

    $scope.tinymceOptions = {
        plugins: 'link image code',
        toolbar: 'undo redo | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright | code '
    };

    $scope.model= "text";
})
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.8/angular.js"></script>  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tinymce/4.9.5/tinymce.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-tinymce/0.0.19/tinymce.js'></script>
  <!-- AngularUI TinyMCE -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <form>
    <textarea ui-tinymce="tinymceOptions" class="text1" id="mytextarea" ng-model="model">Hello, World!</textarea>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Changes, compared to your code:

1. In HTML I have inserted ng-model, since it is required by tinymce directive. I also initialised the value in JavaScript code by `$scope.model= "text";`
2. In head I checked the links and ensure that first AngularJs is loaded (non-minified, so it is possible to see errors, which makes sense), then basic tinymce, then angular-ui-tinymce and finally my code. I have also checked, that all links are not dead.

p.s. Snippet is not working properly. But you can copy code from it and try locally.

Comment: @KamleshSingh, you are welcome. You can mark the answer as accepted, so other users will see, that your question is resolved.